# jquery .replace() with regex prevents selecting all of value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ztNHL/3/

Select the top input, and then tab to the second. It will put your cursor at the end of the value, rather than selecting all. if you remove the javascript and run again, you can see this behavior doesnt happen.

Clueless.

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.numbersOnly').keyup(function (evt) {
        if ($.inArray(evt.which, [37, 38, 39, 40]) != -1) return false;
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,'');
            if (evt.which == 9) this.select(); //<-- re-select field value
    });
});            
​
```

Some other modifications I made:

- pattern made shorter (using `\d` alias)
- cursor keys are re-enabled (in your code they were blocked from working)
- the selection happens only if the tab key was pressed, not merely any key

Comment: And what about float numbers?

Comment: And do not forget about the exclusion `^`.

Comment: Think I'd better go to bed...!

Comment: Я вот тоже думаю, что и мне пора ;)

Comment: Thank you. I went with this solution. Technically, just switching my code to keydown "fixed" it - but this addresses other problems. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing strange. `keyup` event reacts on <kbd>TAB</kbd> and executes your code

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "");
```

witch updates the value of the input field. That's why it first selects the field and then removes the selection.

Comment: I noticed my error and changed it right after to keydown and it fixes... doh. But there are other problems with it that were solved by other in the post. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 2):

There are few other issues like:

**Working demo** Smooth: http://jsfiddle.net/wWxVL/2/

- The left arrow keys don't work.
- The stuff is bit quirky when user type.
- Tab/select all issue (known)

An awesome post here: [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".numbersOnly").keydown(function(event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: I went with Utkanos' solution, though this way taught me a lot and works just as well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

When I tab (in chrome) to the second box, it doesn't go to the end of the value until i let go of the tab key(i.e. on keyup)

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
```

is being executed when you let go of the tab key

Comment: Yeah, I'm a moron. keydown fixes, but there are other problems, as addressed by the other posters.